# Java Generic Interface Return Generics

Tags: java, generics

I found this code from a tutorial and I am guessing this method `getUriBase` return type is `String`, but not clear what part `<T extends IEntity>` is playing in this method and why it is placed in the beginning?

```
public interface IUriMapper {
    <T extends IEntity> String getUriBase(final Class<T> clazz);
}
```

Comment: In this case, it's basically equivalent to `String getUriBase(Class<? extends IEntity> clazz);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the convention of creating a [generic method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html).

> The syntax for a generic method includes a type parameter, inside
>   angle brackets, and appears before the method's return type. For
>   static generic methods, the type parameter section must appear before
>   the method's return type.

If you see then before your return type `String` you defining your type parameter `T`. Now, coming to `<T extends IEntity>`, by this basically you are creating a [bounded type parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html), where-in you are telling the compiler that `T` should only be a subclass of `IEntity`.

An important thing to note is that you need to define `<T extends IEntity>` before your method (*this is what you call "generic method", more info coming...*) because your interface is not a generic type, suppose your interface was like below then you need not to define the `T` type parameter because compiler would know what is the `T` type parameter.

```
public interface IUriMapper<T extends IEntity> {
    String getUriBase(final Class<T> clazz);
}
```

**So, basically generic method are useful (*or in other words meant for situations*) when you want to define your own type.** Consider below example where-in your generic type (*your interface "IUriMapper"*) defines type parameter "T" but for method `getUriBase` you are creating a new type "E"

```
public interface IUriMapper<T extends IEntity> {
    <E extends Number> String getUriBase(final Class<E> clazz);
}
```

[This Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) is best source to learn Generics.

Answer (score 2):

### Generic Types

> The type parameter section, delimited by angle brackets (<>), follows the class name. It specifies the type parameters (also called type variables) T1, T2, ..., and Tn.

```
public class Box {
    private Object object;

    public void set(Object object) { this.object = object; }
    public Object get() { return object; }
}
```

> To update the Box class to use generics, you create a generic type declaration by changing the code "public class Box" to "public class Box". This introduces the type variable, T, that can be used anywhere inside the class.

```
/**
 * Generic version of the Box class.
 * @param <T> the type of the value being boxed
 */
public class Box<T> {
    // T stands for "Type"
    private T t;

    public void set(T t) { this.t = t; }
    public T get() { return t; }
}
```

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

---

### Bounded Type Parameters:

> There may be times when you want to restrict the types that can be used as type arguments in a parameterized type. For example, a method that operates on numbers might only want to accept instances of Number or its subclasses. This is what bounded type parameters are for.

```
public class Box<T> {

    private T t;          

    public void set(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public T get() {
        return t;
    }

    public <U extends Number> void inspect(U u){
        System.out.println("T: " + t.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println("U: " + u.getClass().getName());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box<Integer> integerBox = new Box<Integer>();
        integerBox.set(new Integer(10));
        integerBox.inspect("some text"); // error: this is still String!
    }
}
```

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html

Comment: could you answer how that fit into the interface method case in the question?

Comment: In the case of your question, the parameter that the method is expecting must be a subclass of `IEntity`. Which means there must be some method in `IEntity` that the generic object needs to have